# What age can I expect to not need a stroller?

Tags: toddler, walking

Our daughter is currently 1, and we're contemplating a second child. We're not super happy with our current stroller and are thinking of getting a new one.

We're debating the utility/need of a tandem stroller. The idea is to have our second child when the first is 2 1/2 - 3, so the question comes to, "**At what age can I expect my daughter to not need a stroller?**"

I am of the opinion that my daughter, while able to walk, won't walk quickly, and will get tired, thus we'll need a stroller to accommodate her, but my wife isn't so sure.

Thanks

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**Not *need* a stroller: at around 2½ years of age.**
As soon as your daughter can walk adequate distances, the stroller is no longer technically needed. But  of course the acceptable distance grows shorter when she's tired or in a bad mood. Even for you it can be very convenient for bringing along small amounts of necessary luggage.

**Not *desire* a stroller: at around 4 years of age?**
Depending on how lazy she will become (or be allowed to become), and depending on other modes of carriage (tomjedrz's wagon suggestion), kids would of course love to be chauffeured around for as long as possible, until their curiosity and impatience makes them want to explore on their own.

As an alternative, consider **carrying the new baby in a carrier** while keeping the daughter in the stroller. Babies can be comfortably carried for at least a year, especially if you use suitable equipment.
I'm personally against the *[Baby Björn](http://www.babybjorn.com/products/baby-carriers/)* type of carriers because of inadequate leg support -- I'd recommend a sitting position like in the *[Manduca](http://www.manduca-baby-carrier.eu/)* -- but these details are veering away from your question.

Comment: I second carrying babies in slings or carriers. We love our Ergo.

Comment: The question is definitely might be different for each child personally. I was actually wondering, is there a US LAW which requires you to have a stroller, specially when you to mall!?

Comment: I cannot imagine that any country has a law that demands that you have a stroller.

Answer (score 7):

If you have the funds, get a stroller that can accommodate both kids. In theory, you do not "need" a stroller for a child who walks well enough to keep up with you. In practice, it doesn't work that way, because toddlers and preschoolers get tired, and bored, and consequently difficult. Nothing ruins an afternoon out like an unhappy child.

The common experience in my extended family, which has a dozen children now between 15 and 22, is that the strollers remained useful until the kids outgrew them. They gradually were used less and less as the children got more mobility and endurance, and migrated from person carriers to stuff carriers as the kids got older.

Basically, the stroller allows for outings to be extended and be more fun for all, because the tired kids can rest or sleep or tune out, and more things to keep kids amused can be brought along.

A brother-in-law got a [large wagon](https://a.co/d/0dsHnoP) that filled a similar purpose for the youngest kids until 7 or 8, and is still used for keeping stuff at outdoor events. We go borrow it for our annual pilgrimage to the [LA County Fair](https://www.lacountyfair.com/)!

Comment: +1 for the idea of replacing the stroller with a multipurpose wagon. I'm considering the same. The only downside is that it doesn't collapse for easy transport in the car.

Comment: While useful information, this doesn't answer the question of "what age". The only ages you mention are 7 and 8 yrs... but in relation to usage of a wagon.

Comment: @dpollitt There is no hard and fast answer to the question. My first 2 paragraphs are a direct, though not numerical, answer.

Comment: The "large wagon" link is broken, and the "LA County Fair" one is a redirect. You should probably replace both with the actual pages rather than copying the Google links.

Answer (score 5):

My little boy is 2 years old plus a few months, and since a while (3 months?) we don't use the trolley anymore. I could be a matter of life habits: we use our bikes when we go in the vicinity, and when we go further, by car, it is usually to places like lakes or mountains where trolleys are useless anyway, and then we bring a "baby-backpack". I also can carry him on my shoulder if needed. So I would say: buying a special "two-kids" trolley is probably a bad idea, as it is not necessary and probably not very convenient to use.

There is a comment I don't agree with: "Nothing ruins an afternoon out like an unhappy child". That is not my way to see this. I try to not let my kid, however unhappy, ruin any afternoons of mine, and anyway having or not a trolley should not be a reason for him or her to be unhappy.

This unhappiness thing is an interesting topic. In fact, I actually *train* my kid to be unhappy, by sometime randomly taking the thing he holds from his hands. He cries a bit, and then I do something else with him, playing with the sand on the streets, or finding another object for him to hold. I expect him to be less dramatically affected next time he is "unhappy".

I think being able to accept that things are not always going the way one like is of the highest importance and should be taught early, to everyone. (I can tell that this lesson has not been learned well, even by some very well-kwon adults!)

Comment: I'm sure you mean you train your baby to *cope* with occasional unhappiness, but even so I reject the idea that artificially induced sadness is needed to bolster what life will bring them as a matter of course.

Comment: Yes, "train your baby to cope with occasional unhappiness". And no, it is not some "artificially induced sadness", it is more that if something of no importance is about to happen and I know he will unduly get angry, I will sometime just let that happen, and let him be unhappy, for a short period of time.

Comment: "Letting that happen" is a far cry from "taking the thing he holds". Which do you mean?

Comment: Well, for example if he holds the toy of his friend and don't want to give it back, I may take it.

Answer (score 3):

As @tomjedrz said, they do go from being baby carriers to stuff carriers and are always useful in that regard.

That being said, all babies are very different.  I have a one year old who has never been one for riding in a stroller much.  He wants to be up where he can see things, and now that he's walking, wants to walk for himself.  I still use mine occasionally, but for something like a trip to the mall, I'd just end up trying to hold his hand and push the stroller.

On the other hand, my Mom used her double stroller for my nieces pretty consistently until the older one was about 5.  She'd get out and walk, but then she'd have a place to sit and rest when she got tired and the rest of us were still on the move.

I think even with as infrequently as we use the stroller, it is convenient enough when we do use it that I will get a double stroller when baby #2 is born.  (Baby #1 will be 18 months then.)

Answer (score 2):

Up to about 4 - same as @Torben.

We ended up going through about 8 buggies/strollers with our 3 kids. There was one which had a full reclining position and sunshade which worked very well on holidays in the mediterranean when they were up to 4 years old - in the heat they got tired very quickly so having somewhere they could sleep was essential.

We also kept one just for travelling - very light, with a shoulder strap, so we could carry it through airports, just to make life easier.

To be fair though, we also had a Baby Bjorn (up to about 8 months), a sling (0 - 6 months) and 2 rucksack type carriers (up to 2 years) - and used them all.

Answer (score 2):

How long you will need a stroller definitely depends on your situation.

My kids are 15 months apart. I used a double stroller daily until my youngest turned three and my oldest turned four, because someone usually fell asleep in the car or was too much in need of food or sleep to walk cooperatively. Also, I always had something extra to carry around: groceries, library books, diaper bag, etc., and had no hands to carry one of them.

I also found that prior to age 3 and 4, they would not stay together if we tried to go to the mall or the zoo without a stroller. With the stroller they would stay together. The stroller also gave them a reference point;  for example, once done exploring one store I would say, "Ok back in the stroller," they would oblige, and we would stroll on to the next place. In some instances where they would both run off in different directions, the stroller allowed me to grab the closest one, put them in the stroller, and run after the other one.

Answer (score 2):

Our twin boys where 2 years old when our third child was born. At that point, we still used the double stroller a bit, while carrying our daughter, but within 6 months, we gave the double stroller away and we almost never used a stroller for our third child, always carrying her in a manduca until she could walk far enough. Train stations and airports are so much easier without a stroller (and a lot of fun with a couple of 3 year old boys). We kept the manduca until she was 4 years old for long hikes.

As another answer already said, make sure you get a nice [baby carrier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Babywearing) where the baby or young child has its legs in a natural M position. Carying in the front of your body is painful for your back. As soon as they were a few months old, we carried our children in the back, like backpack (full of love, hugging you). Our children all went to a [forest kindergarden](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forest_kindergarten) (spending all day outside in the forest is really good for their sense of observation and many other skills). Our daughter was carried a lot in a baby carrier, maybe that's why she has good grip and enjoys climbing trees.

For our 4th child, also a girl, we really never used a stroller on trips or during the day, except a vintage Maclaren baby buggy to bring her along with her brothers to the school bus. That was fun, she enjoyed it so much, and her brothers could push her too. Careful, careful now boys.

Answer (score 1):

When my son was about 3 we bought one of those pull-along wagons. That way on long days out we could stick plenty of food, water etc in the wagon, and then once he got tired we could put him in the wagon as well. It worked really well.

Answer (score 0):

One thing that is very handy about having a stroller for a 2-year old is when they need to rest, but you are out in public or in a place where no convenient rest spots are available.

For us, we've travelled with our toddler in a train twice now, and the stroller was exceptionally handy as a place he could safely lay back and nap during those long rides. It is also exceptionally handy to have on long walks through the local mall, where his energy level can suddenly plummet after a long walking session.